# Problem on vscode using extension jupyter notebook with conda virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, conda

On vscode I'm using the jupyter notebook extension and it works.
For example, if I insert in the first cell:

```
print("Miao")
```

It correctly prints "Miao".
The problem is that all the packages/libraries in my virtual environment of conda aren't recognized.
For example:

```
import geopandas
```

not works and tell "module geopandas not found".
But geopandas is in the virtual environment.

My setting.json is

```
{   
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\susim\\anaconda3\\envs\\cubenv\\python.exe"
}
```

and if I press ctrl+shift+ò (to open a new terminal in vscode) it opens a new terminal with the virtual environment cubenv activated.

Ps: If I create a simple python program and I set as python interpreter the same, here all the packages are recognized.
For example `import geopandas` works.

Ps2: If I use the terminal and I activate the virtual environment `conda activate cubenv` and then run `jupyter notebook` here all it works.

Comment: I solved this problem, it was the kernel

Comment: ```(venv) $ pip install ipykernel```

```(venv) $ ipython kernel install --user --name=projectnamev```